# How to check if there are any duplicate sample in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame with massive columns and rows.
Each row is one sample.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,5,9,7,8,6],'col2':[1,5,9,7,9,6], 'col3':[1,5,6,7,8,6]})
```

Assume df is a large DataFrame, I would like to know how to conveniently check if there are any duplicate sample in this pandas DataFrame, then print the row index about duplicate samples.

Thanks

update:
I want to check if row 1 (1,1,1)  equal to row 2 (5,5,5) or row3 (7,7,7) , row4 (8,9,8) and so on. The duplication check is performing by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are several ways, one way is to check the `unique count` for each column against the total `number of rows`.

```py
df.nunique() == df.shape[0]
A    False
B    False
C    False
D    False
dtype: bool
```

`False` value means the column contains duplicate rows

**For UPDATED Question:**
You can just call `duplicated` , it will return you the series of Truthfulness if a row is duplicate or not.

```py
df.duplicated()

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

And, if you want to compare the specific row:

```py
(df == df.iloc[0, :]).all(axis=1)
0     True   #Only the row itself is True.
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear illustration. I have described more in my question. I want to check if row 1 equal to row 5 or row65, row110 and so on . Your solution seems like to check the duplication by column or individual row?

Comment: This is exactly what I want! I don't know why I didn't find this function when I searched. Maybe I use the wrong keywords. Thank you so much.